# Append to Json files with Search and Replace using RipGrep and Sed

Tags: json, jq

It's not really append what I'm looking for  but because I had future noobs in mind, I took the liberty of including it in the title.

I am looking to search for/capture a line-ending `"` and a `]` in the next line (end of file) in json files (many of them). I am using multiline option in ripgrep and forwarding the list of results to be replaced with sed. Running a sole rg without -l lists my results without problems. The problem is with the sed part.

```
cd path/to/folder
rg -l --multiline '(")(\n\])' regex/to/path/to/folders/settings.json | xargs sed -i 's/\("\)\(\n\]\)/\1,\nInputString\n\2/' *.json
```

- I am searching recursively in multiple folders (the regex is correct as I used it for other replacements including git).

What I want is to put a comma after the comma-less line (with the captured quote at the end), put in a new line, put in a string (I'll handle the spaces and quotes myself), another new line and a `]` to close the json settings files.

Sample:

```
[
  "data1",
  "data2",
  "data(n)"
]
```

Desired result:

```
[
  "data1",
  "data2",
  "data(n)",
  "inputstring"
]
```

No matter how I tried, I couldn't make it work. The `*.json` at the end is probably superfluous, just as the brackets in the rg command part. But these are not the problem. What is the problem? Am I missing a sed option/flag? Is there some character that needs to be escaped? Maybe the syntax with the groups in the replacements?

Comment: Please show use sample input & expected output in a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example.](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) Looks a task for `jq`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With the proper tool: [`jq`](https://github.com/stedolan/jq):

```
jq '[ .[], "inputstring" ]' file
```

```
[
  "data1",
  "data2",
  "data(n)",
  "inputstring"
]
```

To edit *in place*:

```
jq '[ .[], "inputstring" ]' file | sponge file
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use `+=` to update the array. Also, use `--arg` to import a string from outside jq.

```bash
jq --arg s 'inputstring' '. += [$s]' file.json
```

```json
[
  "data1",
  "data2",
  "data(n)",
  "inputstring"
]
```

Answer (score -1):

Solution to my case based on the kind answers. I couldn't use `sponge` command and was using `find` this time:

```
find path/to/folder -type f -name "settings.json" -exec sh -c 'jq --argjson s "[\"inputstring\"]" ". += \$s" "{}" | cat > tmp && mv tmp "{}"' \;
```

Answer (score -1):

Under some circumstances, it might make sense to use standard *nix tools. If that is the case, I'd go for simplicity, e.g. in your case:

```
awk -v s="inputstring" '/^  *.*[^,]$/ {print $0 ","; print "  \"" s "\""; next;} {print}'
```